# How can I know @Insert of Room is completed?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlinx.coroutines

> My scenario

I use Coroutines and Room to save my app's user profile data. I have CompleteProfileActivity :in that User fill their information and confirm it( Confirm button ). I send them to server and observe response. If response is success. I save them to my ProfileDatabase.

> My question
>   How can I know my database is updated or my insertion is complete, my deletion is completed not by getting the size? @Insert @Delete is void return methods. So how can I know except the database size?

```
@Dao
interface ProfileDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun saveProfile(model:Profile)

@Query("SELECT * FROM profile_table")
fun getProfile():Deferred<Profile>
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the method call succeeded for insert, then it was succesful, otherwise you'd get an exception.

Also, these don't have to be void-returning methods.

You can have `@Insert` return the type of the primary key in the table, which will be the key of the newly inserted record.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun saveProfile(model: Profile): Int
```

In case of `@Delete`, it will return the number of rows deleted if you return an `Int`:

```
@Delete
fun deleteProfiles(profiles: List<Profile>): Int
```

Same goes for a more manual implementation using `@Query`, returns the number of rows affected if you return an `Int`:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM profiles")
fun deleteAllProfiles(): Int
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just going to read the documentation again now, you save me. Cheers!!!!

Comment: get an error "Not sure how to handle insert method's return type."